# LINQ consider comparing elements by double

Tags: c#, algorithm, linq, logic

my goal is to split IEnumerable of ships by groups.
Group of ships is ships which are within 0.5 of mile between each other.

UPD: say we have a river, like, Mississippi. Ships are being floating through it.
My goal is to group them by their position. Not coordinates but miles (e.g. 19.3 mile) so that if we have a ship being on 19.3 mile and other one is on 19.5 we gather them into one group. But if we have yet another ship on 193 mile we can't add it to out group of two ships we just grouped.

ungroupedShips in a collection of ships we have: (all rivers and places)
IEnumerable.

I wonder how can I consider mile comparing in my query?

```
var orderedShips = from ship in ungroupedShips
                   orderby string.Intern(ship.River), ship.MileMarker ascending
                   group ship by string.Intern(ship.River) into shipRiverGroup
                   select new BargeGroup { Ships = shipRiverGroup };
```

Comment: What is `ungroupedShip`, is it a database driven LINQ provider or Linq-To-Objects?

Comment: Why are you using `string.Intern`?

Comment: Too little informations for a complex task like this. Show the classes and how you measure the distance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I've updated details.

Comment: @juharr because I have to be aware of 1 000 000 ships. If I were about to have such many ships I would need to have one million copies of the very same string in the memory.

Comment: Lets say you have 3 ships one at 19.0 other at 19.3 and the 3rd at 19.5. How many groups will be generated? What ships will be in each group?

Comment: The concept of "Grouping" only applies when you have defined equivalence classes.  But your relationship - two ships being within 0.5 miles of each other - is *not* transitive.  Your relationship defines a graph, not a partition.  (If A, B, C are in a straight line with A at 0, B at 0.3, and C at 0.6, then (A, B) and (B, C) are within 0.5 miles of each other, but (A, C) are not.)

Comment: @JonnyPiazzi one group since they all float within 0.5 miles

Comment: And if you have a fourth ship at 19.8, how many groups do you have, and what are the members? The 19.0, 19.3, and 19.5 are within .5 miles of each other. But the ones at 19.3, 19.5, and 19.8 are within .5 miles of each other, too. There are multiple possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

I not understand your linq, but based in your question:

You can group by intervals of numbers using truncate, like:

```
context.YourTable
    .GroupBy(g => (int)g.YourFieldDouble)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Key);
```

This will group by integer values

If you want to group in 0.5 to 0.5 groups, just use multiplication and division like:

```
context.YourTable
    .GroupBy(g => (int)(g.YourFieldDouble * 2) / 2.0)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Key);
```

Also you can use round method:

```
context.YourTable
    .GroupBy(g => Math.Round((double)g.YourFieldDouble * 2,
                             MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) / 2.0)
    .OrderBy(o => o.Key)
```

Comment: If a ship is at `0.99` and the other at `1.01` they will end up in two different groups isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, if you want this 2 in the same group (the group 1) you need to use round instead truncate.

Comment: That will not solve it. Suppose you  have three ships: `{ A:0.5, B:1.0, C:1.5}`, your code will output one group with two ships and a second group with one ship. But the OP wants two groups of two ships: `{A,B}` and `{B,C}` .

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting what you need to do, can you improve your question? Try to explain better how the group by will be constructed.

Comment: I am not the OP. But the question states that: `Group of ships is ships which are within 0.5 of mile between each other.` . In my example, both `{A,B}` and `{B,C}` match that definition.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not getting what you need to do, can you improve your question? Try to explain better how the group by will be constructed.

Answer (score 1):

From lack of information I will consider you have a `Ship` entity class like that:

```
class Ship
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double MileMarker { get; set; }
    public string River { get; set; }
}
```

So to get all pair of two ships that are nearby each other in the same river:

```
from s1 in context.Ships
from s2 in context.Ships
where Math.Abs(s1.MileMarker - s2.MileMarker) <= 0.5
   && s1.River == s2.River /* guarantee both ships are in same river. */
   && s1.Id != s2.Id /* avoid pair of one ship with itself. */
   && s1.MileMarker < s2.MileMarker /* avoid permutation duplicity */
select new { S1Mile = s1.MileMarker, S2Mile = s2.MileMarker, River = s1.River }
```

With a scenario like:

```
Ships = new List<Ship>
{
    new Ship { Id = 1, MileMarker = 0.2, River = "San" },
    new Ship { Id = 2, MileMarker = 0.4, River = "San" },
    new Ship { Id = 3, MileMarker = 0.8, River = "San" },
    new Ship { Id = 4, MileMarker = 0.1, River = "Joe" },
    new Ship { Id = 5, MileMarker = 0.4, River = "Joe" },
    new Ship { Id = 6, MileMarker = 0.3, River = "Joe" },
};
```

You will get:

```
S1Mile    S2Mile    River

   0.2       0.4    San 
   0.4       0.8    San 
   0.1       0.4    Joe 
   0.1       0.3    Joe 
   0.3       0.4    Joe
```